# Let $f$ be a permutaion of $\{0,\ldots,n\}$. Then the weighted projective space $\mathbb P(q_0,\ldots,q_n)\cong \mathbb P(q_{f(0)},\ldots,q_{f(n)})$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Fix $q_0,\ldots,q_n\in\mathbb Z$ to be $n+1$ coprime integers. Let $S^1$ act on $S^{2n+1}$ as follows - $$\lambda\cdot(z_0,\ldots,z_n)=(\lambda^{q_0}z_0,\ldots,\lambda^{q_n}z_n)$$

$($The resulting quotient space is what is known as the weighted projective space $\mathbb P(q_0,\ldots,q_n))$

I am trying to prove the following -

**Proposition :** Let $f$ be a permutaion of $\{0,\ldots,n\}$. Then the weighted projective space $\mathbb P(q_0,\ldots,q_n)$  is homeomorphic to $\mathbb P(q_{f(0)},\ldots,q_{f(n)})$.

**Attempt at a proof :**

Denote by $(S^{2n+1}/S^1)_f$ the quotient of the action of $S^1$ on $S^{2n+1}$ given by $$t\cdot(z_0,\ldots,z_n)=(t^{q_{f(0)}}z_0,\ldots,t^{q_{f(n)}}z_n)$$ Let each class of elements in it be denoted by $[(z_0,\ldots,z_n)]_f$.

Define $\phi:(S^{2n+1}/S^1)\rightarrow (S^{2n+1}/S^1)_f$ by $[(z_0,\ldots,z_n)]\mapsto[(z_0,\ldots,z_n)]_f$. If $\phi$ is well-defined then we have the diagram,
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
   S^{2n+1}    @>id>>  S^{2n+1}\\
   @VVpV        @VVp_fV\\
   (S^{2n+1}/S^1) @>\phi>> (S^{2n+1}/S^1)_f
 \end{CD}

Where $p$ and $p_f$ are the respective quotient maps. Then $\phi$ is clearly a homeomorphism.

Well-definedness of $\phi$ : **(This is what I am stuck with)**

Suppose $(z'_0,\ldots,z'_n)=(t^{q_0}z_0,\ldots,t^{q_n}z_n)$ for some $t=e^{2\pi i\theta}$. Need a $t_1\in S^1$ such that $(z'_0,\ldots,z'_n)=(t_1^{q_f(0)}z_0,\ldots,t_1^{q_(n)}z_n)$.

I am unable to proceed further.

**Q 1 :** Is my approach correct? Can someone help me proceed?

**Q 2 :** Is $\phi$ an isomorphism of varieties as well?

---

**EDIT**

**Second attempt :**

Since any permutation can be written as the product of transpositions we can WLOG assume $f$ is a transposition, i.e; $f^2=$ identity permutation.

By abuse of notation let $f:S^{2n+1}\to S^{2n+1}$ denote the map $(z_0,\ldots,z_n)\mapsto (z_{f(0)},\ldots,z_{f(n)})$. Denote $S^{2n+1}_f$ as the sphere with permuted co-ordinates which is homeomorphic to $S^{2n+1}$ via $f$. Let $S^1$ act on $S^{2n+1}$ and $S^{2n+1}_f$ as follows - $$\lambda\cdot(z_0,\ldots,z_n)=(\lambda^{q_0}z_0,\ldots,\lambda^{q_n}z_n)$$ $$\lambda\cdot(z_{f(0)},\ldots,z_{f(n)})=(\lambda^{q_0}z_{f(0)},\ldots,\lambda^{q_n}z_{f(n)})$$
**Claim :** $$\mathbb P(q_0,\ldots,q_n)\cong S^{2n+1}_f/S^1\cong \mathbb P(q_{f(0)},\ldots,q_{f(n)})$$

Again I am not sure how to prove this (or if it can be done)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach is almost there, the inverse is given by the same construction for $f^{-1}$, which is also a permutation.